# Aumento de tempo de resposta no IIS 7

Tags: iis, configuração, tempo-de-resposta

Possuo 3 servidores em um *load balance* e um deles vêm apresentando lentidões. Todas elas são em ASP.Net porém há uma aplicação que está consumindo cerca de 30% processamento de uma das máquina. Como eu posso fazer para *tunar* essa aplicação mexendo no IIS?

Já diminuí o tempo de `recycle` do `appPoll` mas não resolveu o problema.